# How to add multiple annotations in Mapview in iphone application

Tags: objective-c, dictionary

Hi friends. I want know that how i can find the hotels or multiplex nearest to my current       location i am using web service but the problem is that i am new in iphone development so, please, provide me some link.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to get familiar with CoreLocation and MapKit.

A MapKit tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial

Apple location documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html